# Esta pergunta não é duplicada

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

Esta pergunta, [Criar colunas no R a partir de outra onde alguns valores são nulos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29062/criar-colunas-no-r-a-partir-de-outra-onde-alguns-valores-s%C3%A3o-nulos), apesar de não estar bem escrita, não é duplicata de [Comparando matrizes de diferentes tamanhos em R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25443/comparando-matrizes-de-diferentes-tamanhos-em-r) .

A primeira pergunta trata de como preencher valores nulos (como por exemplo repetir o valor anterior), enquanto a segunda é basicamente sobre como fazer um merge de bases com dados diferentes.

A pergunta também tem uma resposta, se não exatamente correta - tendo em vista a falta de exemplos na pergunta - ao menos adequada e útil.

Penso que deveria ser reaberta. Já dei meu voto.

Answer (score 2):

Já está reaberta, fui o quinto a votar. Acredito que uma edição e um comentário esclarecendo a diferença teriam ajudado a reabri-la mais cedo. A pergunta [chegou a passar pela fila de reabertura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/17010), mas teve três votos de "deixar encerrada".